# hidden markov models with multiple time independent streams

Tags: hidden-markov-models

I'm trying to figure out if there is a good way to merge two HMMs into one, when the underlying states are the same, but the observations aren't temporally linked.

I have two independent observation streams describing the same hidden state space. The underlying order of each observation stream remains the same, but they are not emitted at the same time.

For instance, say I have audio recordings of two separate speakers reading aloud the same passage of text, where the hidden state space becomes the letters in the text, while the stream of phonemes from each audio comprise the observation space.  Each speaker records the audio separately, and use a different cadence when reading.

I can clearly make a prediction of the text using each speaker independently, and try and reconcile the results after the fact... but I sense that combining the observation streams into a single HMM may produce a better result.

Does anyone know a good way to reconcile this?

Answer (score 1):

Merging the states would require aligning these streams first... ie some kind of log-likelihood optimization.
But its possible to use *statistics* from multiple streams to predict the "observations" - modern data compressors basically do just that.
Eg. see http://www.mattmahoney.net/dc/dce.html#Section_432

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there are methods to merge two HMM's after they have each been fitted to different observation sequences.

But there exists an algotihm to **train one Markov Model on multiple independent observation sequences**.

It is coverered for example in the paper 
"A tutorial to Hidden Markov models and selected applications in speech recognition"
 by Rabiner

Unfortunately, I haven't yet found an **implementiation** of this algorithm.

Here is my corresponding question on stackexchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53256/two-sequences-one-hmm